# Component inside JPanel with Border Layout is not taking full available space

Tags: java, swing, border-layout

I have used BorderLayout.CENTER to add a panel2 inside another panel1. But panel2 doesnt take the full available space. This is what I have done so far

```
       //constructor
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
                new JFXPanel();

                add(getJPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                add(getJBottomPanel(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                getJBottomPanel().add(getTestPanel(),BorderLayout.CENTER);

                Platform.runLater((new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try {
                            initFX(fxPanel);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }   
                    }
                })) ;

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error in swing utilities thread :" + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
```

`getJPanel` method

```
    private JPanel getJPanel(){
    if(panel == null){
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setSize(applicationWidth_600,upperPanelHeight_535);
    panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
    }
    return panel;
}
```

`getJBottomPanel` method

```
    private JPanel getJBottomPanel(){


    if(bPanel == null){
        bPanel = new JPanel();
        bPanel.setSize(200,bottomPanelHeight_65);
        bPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 65));
        bPanel.setBackground(Color.pink);
    }
    return bPanel;
}
```

`getTestPanel` method

```
    private JPanel getTestPanel(){
    if(testPanel == null){
        testPanel = new JPanel();
        testPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
    }

    return testPanel;
}
```

This is the output :- https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/195x383q90/908/wndsCC.png

Comment: This is because the bottom panel does not use `BorderLayout`, but the default `FlowLayout`,

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188); consider adding a [short, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [screenshot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post).

Answer (score 0):

Well I have solved my problem. I was doing a very minor mistake and it proves that a simple mistake can also cause big impact in your application. I forgot to set the the bPanel to Borderlayout. Here is the updated code for method getJBottomPanel

```
private JPanel getJBottomPanel()
{
    if(bPanel == null)
    {
      bPanel = new JPanel();
      bPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 65));
      bPanel.setBackground(Color.pink);
      bPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    }
     return bPanel;
}
```